# require giving error in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I am using angular with nodejs.
I have created a .js file where i am defining the database connection.
File looks likes:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
db.connection.on('open', function ($scope) {
    console.log('db open');
    var newuserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        username: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    });
    console.log('outside');
    var newuser = db.model(newuser, newuserSchema);

});
```

Now, i am trying to access this file in another .js file using require as:

```
require('../models/user_model.js');

registration.click = function(req, res){
console.log('inside');
    var user = new User({ username: $scope.NewUname});
    user.set('firstname', $scope.fName);
    user.set('lastname', $scope.lName);
    user.set('password', $scope.pwd);
    user.set('email', $scope.mail);

    console.dir(user);

    user.save(function(err){
       if(!err)
       {
           console.log('user added successfull');
           alert('user added successfull');
       }
    });

};
```

But, when i run the code, it gives me error as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  (anonymous function)  useradd.js:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Require is not part of Javascript but part of node.js. So I'm guessing you are calling node.js a too late.

You can see some details for you question in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require).