# What is Javascript 'require'?

Tags: javascript

I was analyzing javascript codes in a chrome extension and noticed this in it.

```
require("name of required class/file/module") //Not sure whether it is class,file,module
```

May be its because I'm newbie to programming or something,but I cant find the 'require' keyword in javascript reference or documentation.There is 'import' statement for importing modules.
I googled for require for javascript but all I can find is the 'require' for node.js, the server side scripting using javascript. 
I am talking about chrome extension/client side script.Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Javascript "require"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: `require()` isn't a keyword. It's a function defined either by the environment (Node.js), a library (e.g. RequireJS), or a build tool (e.g., Browserify). [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) and [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) are the common standards related to `require()`, each defining it differently. (The snippet appears to follow CommonJS-style.)

Answer (score 4):

`require` method is part of the [commonjs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) file and module loader. 
You can check more details in their [Sample page](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1#Sample_Code).

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.