# Javascript scope error when calling from another file

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong here? I define a variable in FILE1, then require FILE1 in FILE2, and I require FILE2 in MAIN, so I expected to be able to access the global var `my_global` from both MAIN and FILE2 but it throws an error.

FILE1

```
var my_global=42;
```

FILE2

```
require('FILE1');
var harvesterCount=12;
console.log(harvesterCount+my_global); //throws error
module.exports = function () {...}
```

MAIN

```
require('FILE2');
console.log(my_global); //error here
```

The error statement (from Screeps console):

```
ReferenceError: my_global is not defined
    at module.exports:8:5
    at Object.module.exports.loop:6:5
    at __mainLoop:1:12057
    at eval:2:4
    at Object.c.runCode:6:26869
```

Comment: node.js you are trying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is correct and you should rather export the variable. For e.g.

```
var my_global=42;
exports = {
  my_global:my_global
}
```

You can reference the above exported variable using

```
var m = require('file1');
console.log(m.my_global);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the file using `<script>` tag rather than using `require`

And I see in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require) from stackoverflow about `require`.
Hope this can help you.

> require() is not part of your standard JavaScript. In context to your
>   question and tags, require() is built into Node.js to load modules.
>   The concept is similar to C/Java/Python/[insert more languages here]
>   imports or includes.
>
> The concept of modules is similar to just adding small bits of
>   JavaScript code via a  tags. **Unlike adding a  tag, it
>   doesn't leak the file into the global scope**

Comment: Thanks to your post I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it/5311377#5311377 I had to export the global variable

Comment: You can't make use of `<script>` tag inside Javascript. That is meant for HTML and the question doesn't indicate the user is using HTML. Hence the answer isn't appropriate. Also support your answer by providing code snippets (link are not suitable, as it may get invalid soon).