# Where does the "exports" define in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Take a code segment of the [fs.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/modules/fs.js) for example:

```
exports.write = function (path, content, modeOrOpts) {
    var opts = modeOrOptsToOpts(modeOrOpts);
    // ensure we open for writing
    if ( typeof opts.mode !== 'string' ) {
        opts.mode = 'w';
    } else if ( opts.mode.indexOf('w') == -1 ) {
        opts.mode += 'w';
    }
    var f = exports.open(path, opts);

    f.write(content);
    f.close();
};
```

Now I'm confused with the `exports` object. You can find it in every PhantomJS module but I found no where to define the `exports` object.

Could anyone give me some suggestions about the place where defined the `exports` object?

---

Don't be confused with the `exports` in NodeJS. It's PhantomJS...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require
it's an object that injected to the module by requiring it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phantomJS implemented `require` syntax (same as `NodeJS`)

if you want to include external library, that library is injected with `module` object and `module.exports` is the public object that the require function returns.

```
//myMoudle.js

var _a = 5; //this is private member of the module 

module.exports= {
    a : ()=>{
      return _a;
    },
    setA : newA=>_a=newA;
}
```

The require:

```
//someCode.js
var myModule = require('path/to/myModule')
myModule.a() //5
myModule._a //undefined
myModule.setA(6) //_a is now 6
```

PhantomJS docs example
[requiring webpage module:](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/)

```
var webPage = require('webpage'); //included the module https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/modules/webpage.js 
var page = webPage.create();
```

Included the webPage module, inside this module there's the next code

```
exports.create = function (opts) {
    return decorateNewPage(opts, phantom.createWebPage());
};
```

that allows to use `webPage.create` function where we used the `require` function

Comment: "The phantomJS implemented require syntax", could you please show me the code in PhantomJS which implements the `require` syntax?

Comment: @Sayakiss added in my answer

Comment: I'm still confused... In my opinion, `require` is a function, so it should be defined somewhere(but I can't find)... `exports` is a object, so it should be defined somewhere(but I can't find, either)... That's what really bother me...

Comment: @Sayakiss module is an object that is injected to your module by the compiler (there's no compiler for JS and it's interpreter but nvm), just like `window` in browser, `module.exports` is the object that is returned from the require operation

Comment: @Sayakiss think about it as a `class` instead of `public` your write `exports`.
`public func foo()` becomes `exports.foo = function`, the rest is private (but it's all static, if you require same module many times, it is created only once)

Comment: Okay, now I see that... But PhantomJS doesn't use NodeJS... I think PhantomJS implemented a similar one... So I think it's not `nvm` as you mentioned...

Comment: @Sayakiss of course it doesn't use `NodeJS` I meant the require syntax is same as `NodeJS`. NodeJS is a program just like phantomJS. `NodeJS` uses V8 JS engine, and `PhantomJS` uses QtWebKit