# require('template.jade') in react-starter-kit

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, pug

Can someone maybe explain me, how this build-time `require` works?

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/src/server.js#L89

They are requiring a `jade` template, which package or configuration allows this, I seem unable to find it myself.

```
const template = require('./views/index.jade')
```

I think is much more elegant then:

```
import jade from 'jade'
const template = jade.compile('./views/index.jade')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Javascript "require"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: "`require()` is not part of your standard JavaScript. In context to your question and tags, `require()` is built into Node.js to load *modules*." http://stackoverflow.com/a/9901097/5742681

Comment: In addition to the links above, that project is using [Webpack](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/tools/webpack.config.js) which means that this transformation happens at *build-time*, rather than at *runtime* like `jade.compile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [RGraham mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387568/requiretemplate-jade-in-react-starter-kit#comment62290252_37387568), the `require` call is being "intercepted" during webpack's compilation of the application bundle. This is done using ["loaders"](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) that define particular behaviour for imports of a particular type:

> Loaders allow you to preprocess files as you require() or “load” them.

In this particular case, the loader that does this modification could be one of these (or another that I didn't find in my search):

- https://github.com/bline/jade-html-loader
- https://github.com/webpack/jade-loader

Edit: looking at the [project's own webpack configuration](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/tools/webpack.config.js#L125) we can see it is the second link above:

```
{
  test: /\.jade$/,
  loader: 'jade-loader',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`jade-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/jade-loader) reads the content of the specified file, which make look something like this (Jade string):

```
h1 Hello, #{author}!
```

..and replaces that with a CommonJS JavaScript code similar to this (at compile time):

```
module.exports = function(data) {
  return `<h1>Hello, ${data.name}</h1>`;
};
```