# how to use adapter.js of webRTC-adapter?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, rtc, openwebrtc

I am writing a WebRTC application and have the following problem:

I want to use the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) library.

I have the following index.html:

```
<html>
  <header>
     <script src='../out/adapter.js'></script>
     <script src='../out/main.js'></script>
  </header>
  <body> 
    <video id="localVideo" width='500' autoplay></video> 
  </body>
</html>
```

and my main.js looks like:

```
var adapter=require('webrtc-adapter');
var localVideo=document.querySelector('video#localVideo');
navigator.getUserMedia(media_constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError); 
function handleUserMedia(stream) {        
   localStream = stream;        
   adapter.attachMediaStream(localVideo, stream);        
   console.log('Adding local stream.');  
}
```

but my browser logs the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: You need to use a module loader such as Browserify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`require` is used (and defined) in Node.js environments to load modules. (Not exclusively, for more information check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)).

If you downloaded an adapter.js version from [here](http://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js) and include it the way you do (via `script` tags), you can simple delete the `require(...)` line and you should be good to go.

*Edit: added an example*

```js
console.log(adapter.browserDetails.browser);
```

```html
<script src="http://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: 'code' <html>
 <head>
  <script src='adapter.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   function a()
   {
     alert(detectBrowser());
   }
  
 
     </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <button id='browser' onclick="a()">as</button>
 </body>
</html>'code'  and i got "detectBrowser is not defined".

Comment: excuse me! please me me, WPP. actually i can't use adapter even i did as u said. Could it be something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you made a mistake. Working fine for me, make sure you include the right adapter.js version and read up on it's API and functionality.

Comment: i really don't know how to appreciate your help. Really thanks alot. I did have a big trouble with adapter.js

Comment: I would like to ask you one thing more. That's the library of adapter.js. While using jsoup library, i search for documents for it so that i can use it effectively. But i hardly finded out documents of adapter.js . It really took alot of time if i read whole file to know about it.

Comment: Not sure what you want from me here? Maybe you're looking for this? https://webrtc.org/web-apis/interop/

Comment: sorry to say this. But i did search there and then i saw no lead so i did come here to ask after 2 weeks of searching on internet.

Comment: could i ask u for how to use  function attach(element, stream) in adapter.js?  because i knew it will took more time to search anymore while i need it. Could it be used as "adapter.browser.attach(element, stream)'? Sorry for being annoying like this.

Comment: Could  you please let me contact u via email? Acttually, i am new with javascript, yet my job is invoked a lot with javascript. Iread many tutorials about javascript and try manything but  there is something about this language, i don't understand. It's about  logic of programming and syntax but not about how to write a purpose function.

Answer (score -2):

if you have checked installing adapter js?
check

```
npm webrtc-adapter --version
```

if not showing up in node,  install it to your app

```
npm install --save webrtc-adapter
```