# Why can't I use functions from javascript-files that are imported by require()?

Tags: javascript, require, electron

I started using [electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

In the [index.html of electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/index.html) a JavaScript file is included using `require()`.

```
<script>
  // You can also require other files to run in this process
  require('./renderer.js')
</script>
```

Now I defined a simple function named `flash()` in `renderer.js`, as well as a log output:

```
function flash(text) {
  alert("Text: " + text + "!");
}

console.log("Renderer loaded.");
```

After starting the electron app, I the the log-output in the console of the dev-tools. but calling `flash()` does not work.

When including the script using

```
<script src='./renderer.js'></script>
```

I can call the function.

- **Where does the `require()` function come from?**
- **Why can't I use the function when including the file using `require`?**
- **How can I use function defined in files that are required?**
- **When should I use `require()` and when should I use `src=""`?**

Comment: Please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require

Comment: @GhanshyamBagul that post does not directly answer the question regarding "require()" on Electron. It simply states that "require is part of Node.js/CommonJS". Please read the question thoroughly before leaving a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where does the require() function come from?

The `require` in Electron is pretty much similar to `require` in Node.js. Electron is not just a web browser; it is intended for you to build desktop applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Because it is intended for more than the web, I assume that the creators of Electron added their own little touch to make it an even more awesome piece of technology that you can use. You can read more about it here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules.

> Why can't I use the function when including the file using require?

It's because they are [enclosed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) inside the module, and hence why it isn't available to any other script files.

> How can I use function defined in files that are required?

In order to use the `flash` function, you would need to export it, like so:

```
function flash(text) {
  alert("Text: " + text + "!");
}
module.exports.flash = flash;
// Note: this is how we export. We assign properties to the `module.exports`
//   property, or reassign `module.exports` it to something totally
//   different. In  the end of the day, calls to `require` returns exactly
//   what `module.exports` is set to.

console.log("Renderer loaded.");
```

But that alone won't let you readily use the `flash` function; you will have to
explicitly grab it from the `require` call like so:

```
<script>
  // You can also require other files to run in this process
  var renderer = require('./renderer.js');

  renderer.flash('Some text');
</script>
```

> When should I use require() and when should I use src=""?

Disclaimer: my opinion.

Prefer to use `require` always. Only use `script src=''` when you want to import libraries that don't use `require` but instead opt to declare variables globally.