# How do I implement printJS?

Tags: javascript, printjs

I downloaded printJS but I don't understand what I need to do to use it. Exactly what is to be loaded on my server? When I execute printJS("mypdf") I get an error about not recognizing "require".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Javascript “require”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Javascript "require"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/malt/sz8y92wx/1/ as on the project site have a working example.

Comment: Depending how your dev environment is, you may want to use the compiled file instead. Under the `dist` folder: `print.min.js`. http://printjs.crabbly.com/#documentation

Comment: This project recently added ES6 module support and has many bugs having to do with import. I.E the module name is 'print.js' which won't work with import/require. Also the documentation is incorrect. The fiddle @MaIT posted is just a copy/paste of the incorrect example given which has nothing to do with importing the module. I would advise you to move on until the author fixes these issues,

Comment: @Rorschach120 What's wrong with the documentation?

Comment: @crabbly the section concerning usage with npm is either the wrong example or if it was intentional, then doesnt actually show you how to use the module with npm. On the readme it shows the 'npm install' but not how to use it in a project.

Comment: @Rorschach120 There is nothing wrong with the usage section. The installation section show you how to get the package, but does not go over how to import it. That could be added, however, the usage is the same.