# What is the function of router(app) do in the following code?

Tags: node.js, express

Here are few lines of code.I did not understand their function.I have commented in the code the lines that I have not understood.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var router = require('./app/router'); //not understood
 router(app); //not understood
```

It will be helpful I anyone can explain their function.

Comment: They probably have a `router.js` file in an `api` folder in the project. They're requiring it and using the function.

Comment: ok understood this..but In `router(app)` here app means the folder that is present named as `app ` where router file is present?

Comment: @AndrewLi..Please answer this.

Comment: @AdityaJain "*here app means the folder*" `api` would be the folder (`api` != `app`). In `router(app)`, `app` refers to an object – an instance of an [Application](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app) created by the call to `express()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  sorry for typo here in the question now it is `router(app)`..

Answer (score 0):

> `var router = require('./api/router'); //not understood`

There is plenty of resources out there explaining this. See e.g. [What is this Javascript "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9901082/272735)

> `router(app); //not understood`

`router` is a function returned by `require('./api/router')`. The function takes one parameter `app`.

What the `router` function does ? We can't know that as it is a proprietary code located in you filesystem in a `./api/router` file.

Comment: In `router(app)` here app means the folder that is present named as `app` where router file is present? Am I correct?

Comment: @AdityaJain No. Your questions indicate that you needs to study more JavaScript basics. Please use your preferred JavaScript resources. `require` is not part of the JavaScript but my answer provides a good link to one resource to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[require](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require/) function is the easiest way to include modules that exist in separate files.

**usage file:**

```
var router = require('./app/router'); 
    router(app);
```

router function take app as a parameter for their use.

**support (/app/router.js) file:**

```
export default function(app) {
    // code stuff 
}
```