# How to make use of variable name using array of string in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is removal of duplicate codes like below.

```
import icon1 from './images/abc.png'
import icon2 from './images/xyz.png'
import icon3 from './images/pqr.png'
import icon4 from './images/stu.png'
...

<img src={icon1}/>
<img src={icon2}/>
<img src={icon3}/>
<img src={icon4}/>
...
```

I want to rewrite above code using loop or map function like below conceptually.

```
let array = [1,2,3,4];

{array.map( v =>
  <img src={icon + v} />
);}
```

Sure, it does not work. In using React.js, how can I make use of variable using string concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the best solution, but this one will work.

---

Instead of storing 1,2,3,4 in an array, store the image names like this:

```
let imgArr = ['abc', 'xyz', 'stu'];
```

When use [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require):

```
{
    imgArr.map(v =>
        <img src={require(`./images/${v}.png`)} />
    );
}
```

**Note:** No need to import all the images at the top, if you are using this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable:

```
let ICONS = {
    1: icon1,
    2: icon2,
    3: icon3,
    4: icon4
}
```

Then access its fields

```
{array.map( v =>
    <img src={ICONS[v]} />
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it

```
const icons = [ { id: 1, src: './images/abc.png'},
{ id: 2, src: './images/def.png'} ]  // add more 

{ icons.map( (item) => { 
    <img key={item.id} src={item.src}/>
  })
}
```