# Is it possible to load a module dynamically from a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am using the following code to import some module dynamically using web-packe.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the switch.
Thanks

```js
import React from 'react'
import iconSend from './icon-send.png'
import iconReload from './icon-reload.png'
import iconDownload from './icon-download.png'
import iconAddDoc from './icon-add-doc.png'
import iconAddAgendaItem from './icon-add-agenda-item.png'

const loadIcon = (src) => {
  switch (src) {
    case 'iconSend':
      return iconSend
    case 'iconReload':
      return iconReload
    case 'iconDownload':
      return iconDownload
    case 'iconAddDoc':
      return iconAddDoc
    case 'iconAddAgendaItem':
      return iconAddAgendaItem
  }
}

const Option = ({id, name, isActive, src}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={loadIcon(src)} alt={name} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Option
```

Comment: Instead of import you can use **require**
example: `const iconSend = require('./icon-send.png'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Ways:

1- Use **[require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)** and in src pass the exact name of the image, like this:

```
<img src={require(`./${src}`)} alt={name} />
```

src should be:

```
icon-send.png
icon-reload.png
icon-download.png
icon-add-doc.png
icon-add-agenda-item.png
```

2- Prepare an object with key name and image, use that to get the image directly.

Like this:

```
import iconSend from './icon-send.png'
import iconReload from './icon-reload.png'
import iconDownload from './icon-download.png'
import iconAddDoc from './icon-add-doc.png'
import iconAddAgendaItem from './icon-add-agenda-item.png'

let hash = {
    iconSend,
    iconReload,
    iconDownload,
    iconAddDoc,
    iconAddAgendaItem
}

<img src={ hash[src] } alt={name} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Map. Something like this:
Then you do not need the switch. 
**Notice** that this is react and typescript. If you are using plain react jsx instead of tsx you do not need the *type Source*

```
type Source = 'iconSend'| 'iconReload' | 'iconDownload' | 'iconAddDoc' | 'iconAddAgendaItem';
const icons: Map<Source, string> = new Map<Source, string>();

icons.set('iconSend', iconSend);
icons.set('iconReload', iconReload);
icons.set('iconDownload', iconDownload);
icons.set('iconAddDoc', iconAddDoc);
icons.set('iconAddAgendaItem', iconAddAgendaItem);

const loadIcon = (src) => {
  return icons.get(src);
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: could you write it without type script?

Comment: @Radex That would be the same apart from the icons Map that would be  _const icons = new Map();_

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this,

```
import React from 'react'
import iconSend from './icon-send.png'
import iconReload from './icon-reload.png'
import iconDownload from './icon-download.png'
import iconAddDoc from './icon-add-doc.png'
import iconAddAgendaItem from './icon-add-agenda-item.png'

const loadIcon = (src) => {
   let myDictionary = {
      iconSend: iconSend,
      iconDownload: iconDownload,
      iconAddDoc: iconAddDoc
   };
   return myDictionary[src];
}

const Option = ({id, name, isActive, src}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={loadIcon(src)} alt={name} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Option
```

You can even make loadIcon as a separate file, and use it in all of your app, wherever you need it.