# POST Request to JSON API on HTML Site from Broswer

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, http

I'm trying to use ajax to query the supermarket's search API, and reply with the name, price and the unit pricing. To do this using Python requests, I would use this code:

```
import requests
import json

payload ={
   'Filters':'[]',
   'IsSpecial':'false',
   'Location':'/shop/search/products?searchTerm=banana',
   'PageNumber':'1',
   'PageSize':'24',
   'SearchTerm':'banana',
   'SortType':'TraderRelevance'
}

url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Search/products"

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

print(data['Products'][0]['Name'])
print("$", data['Products'][0]['Products'][0]['Price'], "0", sep='')
print(data['Products'][0]['Products'][0]['CupString'])
print()

print(data['Products'][1]['Name'])
print("$", data['Products'][1]['Products'][0]['Price'], "0", sep='')
print(data['Products'][1]['Products'][0]['CupString'])
print()

print(data['Products'][2]['Name'])
print("$", data['Products'][0]['Products'][2]['Price'], "0", sep='')
print(data['Products'][0]['Products'][2]['CupString'])
print()
```

And so on...

What I am trying to do is replicate this python code to something that can be used in a web browser. Is that something that is possible?

Comment: A PHP script could be appreciated?

Comment: Something like https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in the browser is nearly identical, but of course it's JavaScript, not Python.

You could use the `request-promise` [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise):

```
const request = require('request-promise')

let url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Search/products"
let payload = {
  'Filters': '[]',
  'IsSpecial': 'false',
  'Location': '/shop/search/products?searchTerm=banana',
  'PageNumber': '1',
  'PageSize': '24',
  'SearchTerm': 'banana',
  'SortType': 'TraderRelevance'
}

request
    .post({
      url,
      json: payload,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

You will need to print out or otherwise parse your data inside your `then` method, since JavaScript executes this asynchronously, not synchronously like Python does.

The question of how to include a JavaScript module in the browser is a separate one, but you can find plenty of examples on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require/9901097#9901097) and via Google.

There is also the `fetch` API which has good browser support at this point, and doesn't require you to bring in an outside module.  The syntax is very similar, you can read more on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: I don't know how to use NPM, I have looked into it and have the modules installed on my computer, but how do I put this in the HTML? I'm getting the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'