# Java Script modules initializing function handler

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, handler, require

Going through the socket.io's [get-started](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/), and I come across a module requirement I can't find clear an explanation of:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

the author describes these lines:

> Express initializes app to be a function handler that you can supply to an HTTP server (as seen in line 2)

I haven't found explanations for this usage in any of the documentations for require that I have read. So, what is happening here? Socket.io is irrelevant to my question. It's only referenced to provide a bit of context. Not sure if this is a simple or complex question...

Comment: You're asking how `require()` works? Have you read this question: [**What is this Javascript “require”**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)?

Comment: What is the difference between require('some_module')(); and require('some_module'); ?

Answer (score 0):

When you `require('express')`, you are importing something. That something is whatever the Express framework chooses to *export*. If you look at `index.js` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/index.js), we have the following:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/express');
```

Which you can see it just imports from a sub directory of the project. But you can see it specifically imports `express.js`. By default (shown [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L28)), it exports a function called `createApplication`:

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;

/**
 * Create an express application.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

function createApplication() {
    // ...
}
```

So when you `require('express')` it will resolve to `function createApplication()` which is just a function. Which is why you have the extra `()`, it's just executing/calling the returned function.

See [Higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).