# Vue: binding img src doesn't work but hardcoding it works

Tags: vue.js

When Im binding my image source it can't find the image

```
<template>
 <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" :src="this.offer.resource">
    <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h1>{{offer.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{offer.description}}</p>
        <h2>{{offer.price}}€</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import Offer from '@/models/Offer.js'

export default {

    props: { offer: Offer},
    created: function() {
        console.log(this.offer.resource);

    }
}

</script>
```

I get the error: `offer_pizza.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:3000/@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

the `console.log`prints out the correct path: `@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg`

Howerever when I just hardcode it like this:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg" >
```

it works fine.

Comment: not familiar with vue, but it looks you have problem with relative-absolute path. Check your network tab, you should see requested resources in both cases. Most probably, you request `http://localhost:3000/@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg` and `http://localhost:3000/somehting-here/@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg`

Comment: can you share for us your controller method that returns picture data, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it the way you did, your `offer` object would have to look like this:

```
offer: {
  ...
  resource: require('@/assets/images/offer_pizza.jpg')
}
```

Your current `offer` probably has a string there.

Comment: Thank you that works! could you explain what require() does?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require