# Direct dependency injection

Tags: javascript

I would to pass a module as dependency into another module.

The code looks  something like this

```
const result = module({deps: require(“./dependency”}))
```

`function module` expects `function dependency` as argument.

However I get an error that `dependency` is not a function

However the same code works if I imported `const deps=require('./dependency')` and then pass `deps` into `module` as argument.

Any guidance how we can do dependency injection without declaring const deps

Comment: Your snippet is malformed, you're missing the closing ) for the require call.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact code involved and errors generated - right now you you're saying the error is that "`dependency` is not a function", but there's no reference to `dependency` in your code etc.

Comment: require is a special keyword in for instance nodejs and webpack. It's not part of the javascript standard and might not behave as a function. You don't specify what toolchain you are using. Read this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require

Comment: You've got the wrong quotes.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku fixed that

Comment: @JamesThorpe dependency is the name of module that is imported

Comment: {deps: require(“./dependency”).default} does this work ?

Comment: @Prasanna you are right.. thanks.. i have answered the question with revised code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure why `.default` has to be mentioned when the `dependency` module already defines the function as `export default async function dependency`. However the below code works

```
const result = module({deps: require(“./dependency”}).default)
```

Comment: I later found out default could be avoided if I used module.exports vs common is export