# why am getting server is already running on port 4000 even i have closed the server

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I am running unit test with my node project using Jest library everything was working pretty fine. When I created new test for route authentication it starts showing server is already running on port 4000 even I am using afterEach() function to close the serve but don't know why am still getting server is already running on port 4000.

Even I have removed the new test for route authentication and restart my project by closing all the terminals but whenever I run the project it starts showing error that server is already running on port 4000.

Here is the code in user test file where am closing server properly and on the next test file I am again using same functions for server connection and closing.

```
const request = require("supertest");
const { Genre } = require("../../models/genre");
const { User } = require("../../models/user");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let server;

describe("/api/genres", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require("../../index");
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    server.close();
    await Genre.remove({});
  });
```

second test file code

```
const { User } = require("../../models/user");
const { Genre } = require("../../models/genre");
const request = require("supertest");
describe("auth middleware", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require("../../index");
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    await Genre.remove({});
    server.close();
  });
```

Here is the output of............................
 ● auth middleware › should return 401 if no token is provided

```
listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000

  10 | 
  11 | const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
> 12 | const server = app.listen(port, () =>
     |                    ^
  at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:12:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/integration/auth.test.js:6:14)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Tests:       1 failed, 26 passed, 27 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.606s
Ran all test suites.

Index.js Code

```
const winston = require("winston");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("./startup/logging")();
require("./startup/routes")(app);
require("./startup/db")();
require("./startup/config")();
require("./startup/validation")();

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
);
module.exports = server;
```

Comment: Could you post the code in your `index.js` file?

Comment: calling `app.listen` multiple times does this.

Comment: why you don't await `server.close();`?

Comment: @RobJohansen i have updated the index.js code see

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon i have tried that but no luck

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes it is being called 2 times even am closing the server but its not closing don't know why

Comment: offsite but maybe this will help: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/how-to-correctly-unit-test-express-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in Node.js, but the nature of your bug is very simple; you're trying to listen on a port that is already being listened on.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require) post offers a solid description of `require()`, which I believe is the source of your trouble.

By calling `require("../../index")` in each of your test case programs, you are effectively exporting server **twice**, which results in two `app.listen()` calls.

You would be infinitely better off exporting your server a single time to some main test program, in which you could then run all your test cases by calling `require()` on each of the test files. This approach is much better in the long run as well because adding additional test cases would 1000x easier; you could just write a new test script, export it to your main test program, and append it to your list of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is creating the server (index.js) multiple times. This makes the server trying to listen to the same port in many instances. The Jest documentation reads,

> If you have some work you need to do repeatedly for many tests, you
>   can use beforeEach and afterEach.

It is obvious that you should create the server one time, do all the tests and close it one time. The methods for this are `beforeAll` and `afterAll`.

> In some cases, you only need to do setup once, at the beginning of a
>   file. This can be especially bothersome when the setup is
>   asynchronous, so you can't do it inline. Jest provides beforeAll and
>   afterAll to handle this situation.

So, your test should look like,

```
describe("auth middleware", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    server = require("../../index");
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await Genre.remove({});
    server.close();
  });
```

Comment: Problem is still the same even i have changed the beforeEach and afterEach to beforeAll and afterAll

Comment: Please publish your index.js

Comment: please check above i have edited and added the index.js file