# ReferenceError if calling function of NPM package in Vaadin 14

Tags: javascript, java, npm, vaadin, vaadin14

I want to import a module for one of my .js files and **call my .js file** with **Vaadin 14**. Unfortunately I struggle with importing it and a **ReferenceError** is thrown in the browser.

My view:

```
@Route(value = "jstest", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("jstest")
@JsModule("./sipcall.js")
@NpmPackage(value = "sip.js", version = "0.15.10")
public class SipJsTest extends Div {
    private Button b;
    public SipJsTest() {
        b = new Button();
        b.setText("Execute SIP.js");
        b.addClickListener(listener -> {
            Page page = UI.getCurrent().getPage();
            page.executeJs("executesipcall()");
        });
        add(b);
    }
}
```

**sipcall.js** (the module is named this way) is located in **frontend/sipcall.js/**. If I do a simple console output the function is called correctly. The error appears if I try to use the imported module.

sipcall.js:

```
import "sip.js";

window.executesipcall = function() {
    var ua = new SIP.UA(...) // from the imported module, throws exception
}
```

**node_modules/sip.js/** contains the module that I imported with **@NpmPackage**. The module is also listed in **package.json** with `"sip.js": "0.15.10"`.

Webconsole error:

> client-4FB121A4CC0177A1068809F06428A755.cache.js:57 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: SIP is not defined
>       at window.executesipcall (vaadin-bundle-6b322b28264dafdccb46.cache.js:4505)
>       at Object.eval (eval at St (client-4FB121A4CC0177A1068809F06428A755.cache.js:991),
>   :1:1)

Any ideas why Vaadin does not recognize the import? Is it because it is not imported in global scope (mentioned [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17753553/can-t-use-frontend-js-with-vaadin-14))?

Comment: I'm not too confident in what I'm saying, but are you sure the npmPackage path is correct? the actual sip.js file should be in some kind of subfolder within node_modules, no? For example, Vaadins Button class has the annotation `@NpmPackage(
    value = "@vaadin/vaadin-button",
    version = "2.2.2"
)` --> they don't even specify a single .js file

Comment: Yes, the module is in a subfolder in node_modules/sip.js/<files>

Comment: Yes, the folder name contains the .js ending. The npm package is called this way I think: https://sipjs.com/download/

Comment: Is your sip.js and sipcall.js in the same folder, as you seem to have 'import "sip.js";', which may be failing part and hence 'var ua = new SIP.UA(...)' fails as it was not imported.

Comment: @TatuLund I found a solution by using require() to import the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to use NodeJs' `require()` to import the module instead of `import`. It works but I am not sure why.

sipcall.js:

```
window.executesipcall = function() {
    var sip = require("sip.js");
    var ua = new sip.UA(...)
}
```

[What is require()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)