# Webpack on browser complains about require not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Here is my folder structure:

```
src/
└───public/
    ├───index.js
    ├───controllers/
    ├───css/
    ├───js/
    ├───models/
    ├───vendor/
    └───views/
        └───partials/
```

I know it's not the best folder structure, but it's one of my earlier projects, and I wanted to test webpack on it.

Anyways the `controllers`, `js`, `vendor` all contain javascript code.

My `webpack.dev.config` is on the same level as `src`:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const {merge} = require("webpack-merge");   

module.exports = merge(common, {
    target: 'node',
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    plugins: [

    ],
    module: {

    }
});
```

As you can see it merges from `webpack.common.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
    
module.exports = {
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For now I am hardcoding the location of the bundled js file in my HTML docs, but on the browser when I run this, I see the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` and I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const Datastore = require('nedb');
const db = new Datastore({
    filename: path.join(__dirname, 'public/db/pfam.db'),
    autoload: true
});
module.exports.db = db;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views'));
app.set('img', path.join(__dirname, 'public/img'));
app.set('js', path.join(__dirname, 'public/js'));
app.set('css', path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'));
app.set('controllers', path.join(__dirname, '/public/controllers'));
app.set('db', path.join(__dirname, '/public/db'));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'home',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, '/public/views')
}))

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(require('./public/controllers'))

console.log(`listening on port ... ${port}`)
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Is your project a serverside one? should run on node not in the browser?

Comment: Ahem: `target: 'node',` — Why is a browser involved at all if you aren't targetting one?

Comment: @RazRonen It's both. Basically when express gets a route, like `/`, it renders a page. I know realistically you would split FE and BE, but this is one of those older projects where I didn't know how to do that

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` is because your bundles contains `require` keyword, which is undefined in the browser?

**Why do they contain `require`**?
Because you use `nodeExternals` from [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)

From their docs:

> All node modules will no longer be bundled but will be left as **require**('module').

Comment: I think my challenge is that `require` is not understood on the browser, the bundle file contains `require` which is run on the browser, hence the error

Comment: sorry but I disagree :) Please read this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901097/3470148, require isn't available in the browser.

I think that the deeper issue is that you have the same webpack configuration for both your client and server project. You should have a common configuration and have two builds. One that merge the common with `target: web` and the second with `target: node`