# How to require in quick.db

Tags: javascript, discord, quick.db

I need to require data from `economy.js` to `coinflip.js` what would the command `!coinflip` give the player money

I use quick db for economy

**coinflip**:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`!coinflip`))  {
  
    const randomFlipResult = [
        "Выпал Орел",
        "Выпала Решка"
    ]

    randomflip = [Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFlipResult.length )];
    console.log(randomflip)
  
    const db = require('./economy');
    client.on("message", db);
    fs.writeFile('./economy')
    
    let amount = 200
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(`**${randomFlipResult[randomflip]}**`)
        .setImage(`https://media1.tenor.com/images/6eb5292d9f77435ca9af1be7d6e70093/tenor.gif?itemid=8642365`)
        .setDescription(`Ты Собрал:${amount} коинов`)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, amount) 
        .then(handleCommandsReplyMessage)
        message.delete({Timeout: 20000})
        console.log('Message deleted');
}
```

This file I need required on `coinflip.js`

**economy.js**:

```
const ms = require("parse-ms");
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = async function(message, client, args) {

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (['809175127731339355', '809172949617606677'].includes(message.channel.id)){ 
    if(message.content.startsWith("!money")){
     let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
     let balls = db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`)
         if(balls === null) balls = 0
            const moneyEmbedBalance = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${user} у вас ${balls} денег`);
            message.channel.send(moneyEmbedBalance)
            console.error();
    }    else if(message.content.startsWith("!money")) {message.channel.send('Неа')}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help with here? Are you encountering a specific problem or error?

Comment: I do not know how to link the database with the coinflip file, so this is most likely a problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this Javascript "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)