# TypeScript compilation successful even if referenced file by require is missing

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have Project 1 and Project 2.
After coping some file, lets say it be `validators/index.ts` from Project 1 to Project 2, I experienced a strange problem:
even if files referenced by copied file via `require` are not exists, TypeScript compilation success and no errors are shown.

In short, the code I talking about is something like this:

```js
type BuilderFunc = (factory:IValidatorsFactory) => Validator;
function  registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(builderFunc:BuilderFunc) {
  let validator = executeBuilderFunc(factory, builderFunc);
  //errors handling and duplicate checks cropped away as irrelevant for this issue
  validatorsMap.set(validator.id, validator);
}
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./existing-validator'));
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./other-validator'));
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./missing-validator'));
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./existing-validator3'));
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./forgot-to-copy-file'));
registerMetaTypeViaBuilderFunction(require('./last-validator'));
```

and TypeScript compilation was successful even the `missing-validator.js` and `forgot-to-copy-file` are missing.

Whole point of migration from raw JS to TS was hope to catch this sort of errors automatically by IDE/compiler.

BTW, IDE is WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require is a function, so it's not evaluated at compile time, rather it is invoked at runtime.

It's a runtime "loader".

So there's no way for the compiler to check that the required module / file exists.

For a deeper discussion, see [What is this Javascript "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

If you want compile-time checking, then you probably want "import" instead of "require".

Comment: I accepted your answer, and want add some note: May be I was been confused by TS when sometimes it can be smart enough to give errors reports like "there is no function A in type require('../foobar')" so I expected it would understand that there is NO such file as `./missing-validator') but it seems it just fallback to `any` type, probably, for such case. Meanwhile, for requires like `require("package-name")` IDE is able to report at least a warning. But not in such case somehow.