# I want to load a json script (locally) in html, to use as a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

This is the json file that I want to call in externally, its local to my html file in a folder called 'api' this can't be edited, as on the live environment I won't be able to.

```
{
    "tests": [
        {
            "test_id": "ffc22c5e-1743-49de-9fce-c15df8c15fcc",
            "url": "https://www.url1.com",
            "checkrate": 300,
            "alert_expiration": true,
            "alert_errors": true,
            "alert_mixed_content": true,
            "follow_redirects": true,
            "first_expiration_reminder": 30,
            "second_expiration_reminder": 7,
            "third_expiration_reminder": 1
        },
        {
            "test_id": "52744d25-9492-46b6-999d-af2fcdf87296",
            "url": "https://url1.com/",
            "checkrate": 86400,
            "alert_expiration": true,
            "alert_errors": false,
            "alert_mixed_content": true,
            "follow_redirects": true,
            "first_expiration_reminder": 30,
            "second_expiration_reminder": 7,
            "third_expiration_reminder": 1
        },
        {
            "test_id": "25f171b8-f248-4f63-8e89-ae4813149670",
            "url": "https://url3.com/",
            "checkrate": 600,
            "alert_expiration": false,
            "alert_errors": true,
            "alert_mixed_content": true,
            "follow_redirects": true
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "total_size": 3
    }
}
```

This is the JS I have tried and doesn't work when loading in the json, I am using a script tag on top of my HTML page.

```
var json = require('api/ssltests.json'); //(with path)
var ssltests = '';
      
         $.each(json, function(key, value){
           if(key === 0) {
            ssltests += "<div class=\"row\">";
               $.each(Object.keys(value), function(k, v) {
                ssltests += "<div class=\"cell\">" + v + "</div>";
               });
               ssltests += "</div>";
             }
           
             ssltests += "<div class=\"row\">";
               $.each(Object.keys(value), function(k, v) {
                ssltests += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value[v] + "</div>";
               });
               ssltests += "</div>";
      
         });
```

Comment: You'll have to set up a local server. I would recommend the npm package [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), it requires no setup. Just run `npx http-server` in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `require` on the client-side. As already mentioned in a comment, it's part of CommonJS and available for server-side JavaScript, typically in the scope of NodeJS. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901097/74890) for more details.

If you want to fetch other files, you'll have to use the browser's [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to load the file for you. As mentioned in another comment, to test this locally, you would have to spawn a webserver.

Answer (score -1):

Using a relative path `./` should work.

```
var json = require('./api/ssltests.json');
```

Comment: `require` is CommonJS, that's not available in the browser.