# ipfs-only-hash and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash, ipfs

Could somebody help me with 'ipfs-only-hash'? I'm pretty new with JavaScript and do not know how to add it to my html and js files...

I need to calculate an IPFS hash of the image file (for example, upload with <input type="file" ..>).
What I found is ['ipfs-only-hash'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-only-hash), and its possible implementation (here - hash of the string):

```
const Hash = require('ipfs-only-hash')
Hash.of('hi').then(console.log)
```

But I got all the time errors on "require", tried to change it to 'import Hash from "ipfs-only-hash"', and again got errors... Where and how should I use it in my html-js files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require